# SOLR Read timed out (socket connection timeout) when indexing large amount of data in a collection

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, solrcloud

We are trying to index around 5 billion records existing in hdfs (parquet file) to a collection on solr. We are using solr 7.2.1. We have spawned an emr cluster of 7 data nodes (16 VCores, 128 GB each) and using the same hdfs nodes for storing solr data as well (solr collection created with 7 shards). After running for sometime we see that the rate of indexing becomes slower and some tasks start failing because of 2 main errors (listed below). After indexing around 550 mill or so the job failed because some task failed too many times.

Error 1:

```
scala.MatchError: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out (of class java.net.SocketTimeoutException)
  at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.sendBatchToSolrWithRetry(SolrSupport.scala:358)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$$anonfun$indexDocs$1.apply(SolrSupport.scala:333)
     at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$$anonfun$indexDocs$1.apply(SolrSupport.scala:322)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Error 2:

```
scala.MatchError: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://solr1:8983/solr/connection-2637-config6: 2 Async exceptions during distributed update: 
Broken pipe (Write failed)
Broken pipe (Write failed) (of class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException)
     at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.sendBatchToSolrWithRetry(SolrSupport.scala:358)
       at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$$anonfun$indexDocs$1.apply(SolrSupport.scala:333)
        at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$$anonfun$indexDocs$1.apply(SolrSupport.scala:322)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
      at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Then we tried to divide the larger file in 300 million record files each and then index with some cooling off period in between. We saw that each subsequent task is taking more time (3 hrs for 1st 300 mill, 4.5 hrs for second 300 mill, 6 hr for 3rd. etc.).
Now when we have indexed over 2 billion records even after waiting for 5-6 hours we are still getting a lot of socket timeout exceptions and jobs fails. We believe it might be happening because even after the job shows completed the merging of indexes continues on the backend (we have seen reduction in the number of files present in respective core directories, so thats our guess). Is this true? and for either yes/no is there any way to solve this and improve performance.

These are some other solr configs we have set.

```
SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms30g -Xmx30g"
GC_TUNE="-XX:+UseG1GC  -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled  -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8m  -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=75 -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=20g"

solrconfig.xml

  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.enabled">true</bool>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.slab.count">1</int>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation">true</bool>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.blocksperbank">16384</int>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.read.enabled">true</bool>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.enable">true</bool>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxmergesizemb">16</int>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxcachedmb">192</int>

  <mergePolicyFactory class="org.apache.solr.index.TieredMergePolicyFactory">
          <int name="maxMergeAtOnce">25</int>
          <int name="segmentsPerTier">25</int>
          <double name="noCFSRatio">0.1</double>
        </mergePolicyFactory>

<autoCommit>
       <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime>
       <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
     </autoCommit>

     <autoSoftCommit>
       <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:1200000}</maxTime>
     </autoSoftCommit>
```

Would really appreciate any help at all.

*Checked in executor logs, found more detailed stacktrace.

```
21/08/31 11:35:53 ERROR BaseCloudSolrClient: Request to collection [connection-2637-config6-65536] failed due to (0) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, retry=0 commError=false errorCode=0 
21/08/31 11:35:53 INFO BaseCloudSolrClient: request was not communication error it seems
21/08/31 11:35:53 ERROR SolrSupport$: Send batch to collection connection-2637-config6-65536 failed due to: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Timeout occurred while waiting response from server at: http://solr4:8983/solr/connection-2637-config6-65536
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Timeout occurred while waiting response from server at: http://solr4:8983/solr/connection-2637-config6-65536
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:676)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBSolrClient.doRequest(LBSolrClient.java:368)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBSolrClient.request(LBSolrClient.java:296)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.sendRequest(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:1128)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.request(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:829)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1290)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.sendBatchToSolr(SolrSupport.scala:389)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.sendBatchToSolrWithRetry(SolrSupport.scala:354)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$$anonfun$indexDocs$1.apply(SolrSupport.scala:333)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$$anonfun$indexDocs$1.apply(SolrSupport.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
    at shaded.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at shaded.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at shaded.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:564)
    ... 24 more
21/08/31 11:35:53 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 75.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 77)
scala.MatchError: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out (of class java.net.SocketTimeoutException)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.sendBatchToSolrWithRetry(SolrSupport.scala:358)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$$anonfun$indexDocs$1.apply(SolrSupport.scala:333)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$$anonfun$indexDocs$1.apply(SolrSupport.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```